# iOS downloading tar file from https url

Tags: ios5, https, download, nsurlconnection

I'm attempting to download a file from an https url. It works fine using http, but it just won't do it for https. I will post my current code below, but for personal purposes I don't want to release the ip address used for the URL, so in it's place I'll put "ipAddress". I should mention that the https is from a self-signed cert.

```
-(void)downloadPDF: (NSInteger)numDay {

NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@%@%@", homeDir, @"Documents/", @"File", @".tar"];
NSString *dirPath = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@", homeDir, @"Documents/"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"ipAddress", @'File", @".tar"]];

NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
[mywebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];

}
```

I've tried numerous things other things, from using the NSURLConnection to downloading entire libraries, but I must be missing something. I also have:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

}
```

In my app delegate .m file as mentioned in other files. Any help would be appreciated, and if you need additional information, please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

https requires a fully qualified domain address (FQDA).  It doesn't work with an IP.

Comment: Is this something only for iOS? I'm able to download the items in question from browsers, even on my iPad.

Comment: It's something for https.  The ssl certificate has the FQDN embedded in it, so if the url you're pointing at doesn't match, it should fail.